# PHP SQL SELECT query works in every table except one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've written a function in php which retrieves a record from a given table using an identifier:

```
function selectRecordUsingID($table, $id_name, $id) {

    $returnArray = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$id_name."='".$id."'";

    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

    if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {

        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if (!empty($row)) {
            $returnArray = $row;
        }
    }
    return $returnArray;
}
```

This will retrieve a record from any of the tables in my database, for example:

```
selectRecordUsingID("groups","group_id", 16)
```

However, this function will not retrieve any data from *one* of my tables: "users"
The datatype of $id, which I'm using to find a "users" record, is exactly the same as the one used to find a "groups" record.

Even if I echo the $sql (SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='16'), copy it and paste it into phpMyAdmin, the code still works.

If I use `echo json_encode($result);` straight after the query, I get `{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}`

As of right now, I can't find a discernible difference between the users table and another table such as the groups table.

Comment: Try checking for [mysqli_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Also, you can create a parameterized query and pass the id in as a parameter, which would solve any quoting issues that may be happening.

Comment: have you tried removing the quotes around the number?

Comment: Don't appear to be getting any errors when using mysqli->error in various places, also removing the quotes makes no difference to the result.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post comments yet, but do you have access to phpMyAdmin through your control panel or in your localhost environment? If so, just type the query directly into phpMyAdmin and see what happens. I find it to be one of the fastest ways to troubleshoot a query being used in PHP to see if the problem is bad SQL or bad PHP.

Comment: The SQL works fine when a put the query in, it is very weird indeed

Comment: If the SQL is good, then most likely the problem is how the SQL query is being stitched together by PHP. Can you show the actual line of PHP code that calls your selectRecordUsingID function and inserts the parameters for the users table call?

Comment: The actual line that calls it is: $user = $access->selectRecordUsingID("users", "user_id", 16)

Comment: So your selectRecordUsingID is a method in your $access object? In your code above it shows as a simple PHP function. Do you call that function as a method from the $access object when you use it on other tables in your database?

Comment: Good thinking! I do infact use this $access object for all the SQL queries in my program so that can't be the problem.

Comment: So your object method works on every table except 'users'? Is it possible that the database user you are using in your PHP script does not have SELECT permissions on the 'users' table? This is not common, as you normally grant similar access to all tables in a given database. Just trying to figure out what's up...this is a good brain teaser!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154930/discussion-between-ingo-and-legatro).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and I'm sharing my solution incase someone else has this same problem.

It turns out that my issue was *(and I still haven't narrowed down exactly what)* a character in one of the fields that was causing the `PHP` to mess up.

My solution was to not include that field (for me it was the file name).

So instead of selecting everything, I just included the fields I needed for that page.

###### Previous

```
SELECT x.* FROM table x;
```

###### My Solution

```sql
SELECT x.field1, x.field2, ... FROM table x;
```

And yes, I used parameter binding for my insert statement.